# GET from js on django

Tags: javascript, python, django

have html this 3 droplist \ 2 button, js send GET with 3 variables mar, yer, kpp

```
  function validate() {
     var mar = document.forms.form_id.m.value;
     var yer = document.forms.form_id.y.value;
     var kpp = document.forms.form_id.k.value;

     return mar, yer, kpp;
    }
    </script>


    <body style="background: transparent; border: none;">
    <form action="/search/" method="get" id="form_id" type="submit" onSubmit="return validate();">
    <table>
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center">
    <br>
        <select id="m">
            <option value="">Марка</option>
            {% for article in articles %}
                <option value="{{ article }}">{{ article }}</option>
            {% endfor %}
        </select>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center">
    <br>
        <select id="y">
            <option value="">Год выпуска</option>
            <option value="2016">2016</option>

        </select>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center">
    <br>
        <select id="k">
            <option value="">Коробка передач</option>
            <option value="mt">Механика</option>

        </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td colspan="3" style="text-align:center">
      <input type="submit"  value="Отправить">
      <input type="reset"  value="Очистить">
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
    </body>
```

and def

```
def search(request):
 if 'mar' in request.GET and request.GET['mar']:
    q = request.GET['mar']
    list = AutoParsingMan.objects.filter(marka=q)
    return render_to_response('Mysitez/seach.html',
        {'list': list, 'querty': q})
 else:
    return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

why not work this 1 variable?(mar) and how create def for 3 variales?(mar, yer, kpp)

model.py

```
class AutoParsingMan(models.Model):
 date_ins = models.DateTimeField()
 date_change = models.DateTimeField()
 change = models.CharField(max_length=15)
 date = models.DateTimeField()
 date_task = models.DateField()
 marka = models.CharField(max_length=50)
 year = models.IntegerField()
 kpp = models.CharField(max_length=50)

 class Meta:
    managed = False
    db_table = 'auto_parsing_man'

 def __str__(self):
    return self.marka, self.year, self.kpp
```

error it - MultiValueDictKeyError at /search/ "'mar'"

```
 def search(request):
if 'mar' in request.GET and request.GET['mar'] and request.GET['year'] and request.GET['kpp']:
    q = request.GET['mar']
    y = request.GET['year']
    k = request.GET['kpp']
    list = AutoParsingMan.objects.filter(marka=q, year=y, kpp=k)
    return render_to_response('Mysitez/seach.html',
        {'list': list, 'querty': q})
else:
    return HttpResponse('Please submit a search term.')
```

Comment: What is the error? What is not working?

Comment: i dont know =) every time   -  'Please submit a search term.' if del js logic for value all works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all Selcuk is right, you shall build your question better.  Questions shall be as objective as possible and yours is quite vague.  Yet, i can see where your issue lies.

You confused JavaScript with HTML Forms.  They're two separate specifications which aim to be independent from each other.  Before building a JavaScript powered form you should first build the form in pure HTML, and once that works you shall add JavaScript on top of it.

For your issue at hand you used the `mar` name as a JavaScript variable name, which will never be sent by the HTML form because HTML forms are not aware of JavaScript variables.  Instead you shall use the `name=` parameter on your `select` tags as follows:

```
<br>
    <select id="m" name="mar">
        <option value="">Марка</option>
        {% for article in articles %}
            <option value="{{ article }}">{{ article }}</option>
        {% endfor %}
    </select>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center">
<br>
    <select id="y" name="yer">
        <option value="">Год выпуска</option>
        <option value="2016">2016</option>

    </select>
</td>
<td style="text-align:center">
<br>
    <select id="k" name="kpp">
        <option value="">Коробка передач</option>
        <option value="mt">Механика</option>

    </select>
</td>
```

The HTML form will send the `mar` variable with the option of whatever article was selected from the dropdown.

---

### Note

That code style might be okay for learning django and/or web development in general but in the real world you shall delegate the construction of the form to django, in a file often called `forms.py`.  Django has a form engine that gives much better compatibility than hardcoding a form in the template.

Comment: thx, i have nice GET and my js now works ?mar=Mercedes-Benz&year=1995&kpp=MT
 but only thing I can not understand why there was a query variable YEAR I always used other yer y ...

Comment: >Django has a form engine - yes im tried but i dont know about base thing - it so hard for me now

Comment: The only place "year" can come from is `<select name="year">`.  The search function of your editor shall be enough to find it.  Moreover, that is something that an editor that corrects words in strings would do (you should disable such feature if that is the case)

Comment: <select id="y" name="yer" > - not have idea , pls looking on my new seach def in post, what a you think about? =)